# File upload works fine but form data not going to fetch with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I use Spring MVC 4 with my website.

When I use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for file upload form data will not be fetched and when I remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` then form data will be fetched properly but file upload will not work.

Please guide me why does this happen.

My code is below.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Hello! This is the default welcome page for a Spring Web MVC project.</p>
        <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file1"><br>
            <input type="text" name="nm"><br>
            <input type="text" name="age">
            <input type="submit" name="sub" value="upload">

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**success.jsp**

```
<%-- 
    Document   : success
    Created on : Mar 1, 2016, 11:19:45 AM
    Author     : Vishal
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>File uploaded</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**FileControl.java**

```
package Myc;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author sai
 */
@Controller
public class FileControl {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String fileup(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {

        String path = req.getRealPath("/uploadimg");
        path = path.substring(0, path.indexOf("\\build"));
        path = path + "\\web\\uploadimg\\";
        String name=req.getParameter("nm");  //not able to fetch value
        String age=req.getParameter("age");  //not able to fetch value
        System.out.println(name); 
        System.out.println(age);
       DiskFileItemFactory d = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload uploader = new ServletFileUpload(d);
        try {
            List<FileItem> lst = uploader.parseRequest(req);
            for (FileItem fileItem : lst) {
                if(fileItem.isFormField()==false){
                    fileItem.write(new File(path+"/"+fileItem.getName()));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "fail";
        }
        return "success";

    }
}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd"> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="Myc"/>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />



</beans>
```

Comment: Has my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed `FileControl` controller.

- First of all you have to use `fileItem` object to get parameters' values.
- I also add check if `\web\uploading\` exist.

**FileControl.java**

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author sai
 */
@Controller
public class FileControl {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/home","/"})
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String fileup(HttpServletRequest req) {

        String path = req.getRealPath("/uploadimg");
        path = path.substring(0, path.indexOf("\\build"));
        path = path + "\\web\\uploading\\";

        String name;
        String age;
        DiskFileItemFactory d = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload uploader = new ServletFileUpload(d);
        try {
            List<FileItem> lst = uploader.parseRequest(req);
            for (FileItem fileItem : lst) {
                if (fileItem.isFormField()) {
                    if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("nm")) {
                        name = fileItem.getString();
                        System.out.println(name);
                    } else if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("age")) {
                        age = fileItem.getString();
                        System.out.println(age);
                    }
                } else {
                    File savingPath = new File(path);

                    if (!savingPath.exists()) {
                        savingPath.mkdirs();

                    }
                    fileItem.write(new File(path+"/"+fileItem.getName()));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "fail";
        }
        return "success";

    }
}
```